# Gloss reflection

Tags: materials, node-editor, light

[image]

Why my lamp looks black in the mirror reflection?

Comment: In Cycles Render maybe go to the Properties panel > Render > Light Paths > and change the Transparency?

Comment: Please share your .blend file, I'm unable to reproduce this in blender. (Reflection of glass object works fine). If sharing the file is not possible please post your render settings and material setups.

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=27638669086918514220 here

Answer (score 1):

The Problem lies in the node setup for the glass material:

[image: Orignial]

As the nodes are set up, the mirrored object is considered to be transparent, while the direct object has the glass material. Additionally the material on the transparent object is a lot darker.

I guess this setup is used to speed up a render, however it doesn't work well with reflections. (There might be another reason I don't see yet, probably light finding it's way out more easily)

The easiest fix would be to just connect the glass node directly,[image: direct connection] which will give the expected result.

If you can get away with it, you can match the color input of the transparent material to the glass material. The effect is less noticeable.